# Issue with Nested html tags

Tags: regex

I have regex which works searching html `<h>` family tags but does not work if any other tag inside `<h>`. See the examples below.

```
<h([\d]).*>\s*[\d]*\s?[.]?\s?([^<]+)<\/h([\d])>
```

**It works**

```
<h2 style="margin-top:1em;">What is Python?</h2>
```

**It does not work**

```
<h2 style="margin-top:1em;">Python Jobs<span class="blink">New!</span></h2>
```

How to capture this `Python Jobs<span class="blink">New!</span>` as second group? Need 3 capturing groups - `2` of h2, `Python Jobs<span class="blink">New!</span>` as second group and `2` of closing h2.

Comment: `([^<]+)` keeps it from matching nested tags.

Comment: Thanks, just found the same. How to capture `Python Jobs<span class="blink">New!</span>` as second group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`([^<]+)` means to match a sequence of anything *except* `<` before `</h2>`. Since the nested tags contain `<` characters, this won't match them.

Use `.+?` to match the contents of the tag. The `?` makes it non-greedy, so it will stop when it gets to the first `</h#>`.

You can also use a back-reference in the `</h#>` part of the match, so the closing tag is forced to match the opening tag.

```
<h(\d).*?>\s*\d*\s?\.?\s?(.+?)<\/h(\1)>
```

BTW, there's no need to put `\d` inside `[]`.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Sorry for not being clear. I need 3 capturing groups - `2` of h2,  `Python Jobs<span class="blink">New!</span>` as second group and `2` of closing h2.

Comment: Why do you need a capturing group for the closing tag, since it's the same as the opening tag? Anyway, I added a capturing group around `\1`.

Comment: Thanks, second group in your solution returns `New!</span>`. I need `Python Jobs<span class="blink">New!</span>`

Comment: Use a non-greedy `.*?` before `>`